# Why does javascript insist on braces for a function but not for anything else?

Tags: javascript, syntax

In javascript I can have, for example,

```
var a = 1;
while (a < 10) a++;

if (a === 10) a = 1;
```

So there are situations where braces are not required (though I usually put them in for clarity and to stop jshint from bothering me about their lack.)

Curiously (to me anyway) `function` doesn't work the same. I do

```
function bar(a) { return a + 1; }
```

but can't do

```
function foo(a) return bar(a);
```

What is so different about `function` that it can't behave like `if` and `while` etc?

Comment: with es6, you can do var a= ()=> console.log('1' ) for a function. No braces required

Comment: functions have function level scope, but there is no block level scope. Ofcourse it changed with let

Comment: `but can't do` You *can* do that, actually, if you use an arrow function instead. `const bar = a => a + 1` and `const foo = a => bar(a)`

Comment: Ahh ... I'm still stuck in the ES3 universe. That explains it.

Comment: As to "why", that's just the way the syntax rules are.

Comment: Why? Because a regular function body is not an [expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Expressions)

Answer (score 4):

Eliminating braces for single line statements/expressions is a common pattern across many languages.

It's just syntactic sugar for the (lazy :)) programmer.

If you have multiple statements within the `if` or `while`, you would still have to write the `{}` around them.

I would personally suggest always doing so because forgetting `{}` could lead to non-obvious bugs sometimes:

```js
let i = 0;
if (i > 0)
  i++;
  console.log('this still happens');
```

Addition of arrow functions in ES6 allows this same behavior with functions:

Your function:

```
function bar(a) { return a + 1; }
```

Could be written without `{}` because it has a single expression:

```
const bar = a => a + 1;
```

But omitting `{}` for multiple operations would again be a bug:

```js
let x = x => x + 1; console.log('this still happens');
```

You could get away with using the [`,`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) operator to chain expressions:

```js
let i = 0;
if (i > 0)
  i++, // <-- notice the comma
  console.log('now this does not happen');
```

But that arguably makes for far less readable code.

Bottom line is, using `{}` by default is a good choice in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

It's all about syntax.

In scheme, a function maybe looks like this:

```
(define (square x)
    (* x x))
```

In python, a function maybe looks like this:

```
def square(x):
    return x * x
```

So, JavaScript Function Declaration Statement is:

```
function name_this_is_function_header(...parameters) {
    // and this is function body
    // statements
}
```

It must include a body which notation is { } . (though, ES6 add a syntax sugar for arrow function, () => { } , you can omit { } if only one statement in it, anyway)

function is a token, ( ) is a pair of tokens, { } also a pair of tokens, compiler or interpreter treat them all as a whole abstraction named JavaScript function.

JavaScript borrowed a lot syntax from Java, Java did the same thing to C++, C++ did the same thing to C ... , that's why.

For statement, such as if and while, it's syntax:

```
if (condition) one-statement;
while (condition) one-statement;
```

So, it's all about statement, statement could be single, could be compound.

Single statement don't need { }, compound statement is just several single statements included by { } tokens or notations. If you need several statements after true, you must use compound statement as a whole.

It's not about something mysterious, It's just how do you write it to express.